# Page numbering is starting from 2

Tags: page-numbering

In my report, I have title page, then abstract page, followed by ToC. Then I get to chapter one where I want to start numbering from in arabic. But in my code numbering was starting from ToC so I used `\thispagestyle{empty}` after ToC and abstract, and now they have no numbering but still Chapter one starts from number 2 and there is no page numbered one. I would like it to start from number 1.

Here is the code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}    
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,calc}
\setlength\parskip{\baselineskip}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\title{Group Rings}
\author{Bhaskar Vashishth}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\abstract
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Prelimanries}
 blah blah
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

`\pagenumbering` and `\thispagestyle` related stuff almost always need a `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` before `\pagenumbering`.

(I've omitted a screenshot for the sake of simplicity)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}    
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,calc}
\setlength\parskip{\baselineskip}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\title{Group Rings}
\author{Bhaskar Vashishth}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\abstract
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage %%%% Add this one here!
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Prelimanries}
 blah blah
\end{document}
```

Comment: always use `cleardoublepage` before pagenumbering.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Ok, but `\clearpage` works too (in this case)

Comment: Both works fine. But  Ii will remember to use `\clearpage` from now on always

Comment: Yes, `report` is `oneside` by default, but as soon as one goes into `twoside` mode, it fails. `As \cleardoublepage` makes a `\clearpage` in onesidemode, there is no harm in always using `\cleardoublepage`.